# Getting data in console but shows undefined in main output

Tags: javascript, api, electron, axios

I'm working on a app with electron using axios to get api data, but when i use to display data it shows undefined in screen and when i output it, it shows the correct value!! Some help would be appreciated!

```
const electron = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const BrowserWindow = electron.remote.BrowserWindow;
const axios = require('axios');

const notifyBtn = document.querySelector('.notify-btn');
const price = document.querySelector('.price');
const targetPrice = document.querySelector('.target-price');

function  getBTC(){
  axios.get('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=BTC&tsyms=USD&api_key={api_key}')
        .then(function(response) {
            let cryptos = response.data;
            price.innerHTML = '$'+cryptos;
            console.log(response.data);
        });
}

getBTC();
setInterval(getBTC, 30000);
```

I  get a output in console:
Object: USD: 3560.263(Current price of bitcoin)
I get output on main screen:
'undefined'

I think its because it an object so how can i display an object?
I may be wrong!!
ThankYou!!

Comment: Is `price.innerHTML = '$'.cryptos;` meant to be `price.innerHTML = '$' + cryptos;`? Or something similar? I imagine the string `'$'` wouldn't have a property called cryptos

Comment: ThankYou i corrected that but now I get '$[Object object] ' on main output

Comment: The response data is an object.  What you saw in the console is showing you that `cryptos` is an object that has the property `{ USD: 3560.263 }`.  So to access the value you use `cryptos.USD`

Comment: Ohh thankyou for explaining, i got my doubts cleared!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not

```
price.innerHTML = '$'.cryptos;
// but
price.innerHTML = '$' + cryptos.USD;
```

Add `.USD` because cryptos is an object. And the value is saved into the key `USD`

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the *property* of a string.

```
price.innerHTML = '$'.cryptos;
                       ^^^ property
```

I think you wanted to concat values with a + operator

```
price.innerHTML = '$' + cryptos;
```

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
price.innerHTML = '$'+cryptos.USD;
```

Comment: Thankyou so much it worked!! But can explain why USD i cant understand!!

Comment: @Cybil structure of your response is type of object: ```{USD: 3560.263}```. so you need key to get value

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve with '$'.cryptos; ?

If you are trying to concatenate some strings this is not how it works! 
try `"$"+cryptos`

Answer (score 1):

You should use only primitive type variables when composing a string.

If you want to show an object, you could simply use [`JSON.stringify(cryptos)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to obtain the JSON string of the whole object.

Otherwise, you could print any other object property that is a primitive type, like `cryptos.USD`.